# What is the meaning of __main__ here?

Tags: python

```
class  RoundFloat(float):
  def __new__(cls,val):
    x=float.__new__(cls,round(val,2))
    print x, type(x)

>>>RoundFloat(1.785)
1.78   <class '__main__.RoundFloat'>
```

What is the meaning of  **main**  here?
is the same meaning as in the  `if  __name__="__main__"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RoundFloat` is an attribute of `__main__` (the file that is running) hence `'__main__.RoundFloat'`. If the class came from an imported module, `__main__` would be replaced by the module name.

The purpose of `if __name__ == '__main__'` is to check whether the module is the top-level script, and if it is, execute a block of code. If it was being imported, that block of code wouldn't execute, since `__name__` would be the name of the module instead.

Answer (score 1):

`__main__` is a toplevel script environment — it is the built-in module in which a script is executed.

See the [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html#module-__main__)

Answer (score 1):

That is the name of the top-level script that you run. It was not imported as a module. If your code was imported as a module, that part would be replaced by the module name. The attribute `__name__` is the module name. The top-level script has the name `__main__`.

Answer (score 1):

You're running `RoundFloat` in the main sequence because it doesn't belong to any other class.

If you put the `RoundFloat` class inside another class, you will probably get either `SomeOtherClass.RoundFloat` or `main.SomeOtherClass.RoundFloat`.

(I'm not sure if "main sequence" is the proper Python term, but hopefully you catch what I mean.)